# Set property value containing it's own value plus other property value

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, properties

So I have a WPF window. There are TextBoxes "Login" and "Ip Address" which are binded to "Login" and "IpAddress" properties. What I need is to save property Login into database as login@ipAddress.

I tried this, but it goes wrong:

```
    public string Login
    {
        get { return _TModel.Login; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _TModel.Login)
                return;

            _TModel.Login = value + "@" + IpAddress;

            base.OnPropertyChanged("Login");
        }
    }
```

How can I do that? BTW I'm using NHibernate to work with the DB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@` with `"@"`:

```
public string Login
{
    get { return _TModel.Login; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _TModel.Login)
            return;

        value = string.Empty;
        _TModel.Login = value + "@" + IpAddress;

        base.OnPropertyChanged("Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: No the problem is not in that. If do like this, and at first a type in the ipAddress and after login after each key press I get the @ipaddress. so login is like that: s@10.0.0.1ss@10.0.0.1sss@10.0.0.1